# Is this LED cover a commercial product?

Tags: led, identification, components

I am trying to build a fork sensor. While I am OK at electronics stuff, for the first time in my life I took active role in making a finished product. Looking at our competitors designs, I noticed a part which helps keeping the 3 mm LED and photodiode fixed on the case:

[image: Part on product]

[image: Part removed]

The part also has a glass (or plastic?) part on the aperture, protecting it.

What I wonder is if it is a commercial product, that is readily available to buy, or is it specially manufactured? The most related thing to this is called "LED bezel", but this is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Does it focus the LED beam?  Possibly a LED focusing lens.

Comment: How many terminals it has?

Comment: @Electron:  No terminals.  It is a mechanical part that you put an LED into.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat no, the lens is flat.

Comment: The flat part may be protecting the lens.  But @StainlessSteelRat is likely correct.  It's the only thing that makes sense.  But then I am only guessing at what  a fork sensor is.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it is pointed at a detector, it is most likely an optical collimating (focusing) lens.

When when the photons are emitted from the LED, the photons spread out.

If a spot lens is used, the radiant intensity increases by collimating the photons into a narrow beam.

**Example:**

A 1200 mcd LED with a view angle of 60°
When collimated to a 1° beam, the intensity increases to 4,000,000 mcd.
Source:  [Lumen Candela Calculator](https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/light/lumen-to-candela-calculator.html)

When comparing LEDs, if it is a visible color rated in mcd, you must convert the photometric mcd to radiometric Watts.

The conversion factors for RGB are:
450 nm deep blue: 0.039
470 nm blue: 0.016
530 nm green: 0.002
625 nm  red:  0.005
660 nm deep red: 0.024
720 nm far red: 1.398

Deep blue is the most efficient LED radiometric and quantum (µmol) visible color.
Infrared is the preferred for photo detectors.

---

[Goolge Images of "led beam collimating lens"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&biw=3544&bih=1902&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=_OJIXP2zGYaG5wKg1rygCA&q=led%20beam%20collimating%20lens&oq=led%20beam%20collimating%20lens&gs_l=img.12...324288.326461..329948...0.0..0.68.536.9......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30j0i8i7i30j0i24.kgE-wLe1Nb4)

---

[image]

---

> no, the lens is flat.

**Notice how flat the exposed lens is.**

[image]